# Set task properties (or command line args) using Gradle Tooling API

Tags: gradle, gradle-tooling-api

I want to use the Gradle Tooling API to invoke Gradle from an Eclipse plugin through the Buildship plug-ins. I am able to run basic tasks without problems.

One of my use cases is to execute the `gradle init` task in a new project folder, but to work non-interactively I have to pass the `--type` command line argument (or set the `type` property) on the `init` task. I can't find any way in the tooling API to set the properties of a task or to pass a task-specific command line argument.

I have tried `BuildLauncher.addArgument("--type", "plain")` but this is interpreted as an argument to Gradle itself, which is invalid.

How can I pass the `--type plain` argument to the `init` task?

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [docs here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/ConfigurableLauncher.html#withArguments-java.lang.String...-), I discovered you can set the task arguments via the Gradle command line build arguments. The important bit in the docs is:

> Also, the task names configured by BuildLauncher.forTasks(String...) can be overridden if you happen to specify other tasks via the build arguments.

In my case I wanted to run `gradle tasks --all` via the tooling api. To get this working, I don't specify the task to run via `forTasks()`, I simply do not call that method. I set the task to run as part of the *arguments* via `withArguments()`. (In this case the arguments will be `tasks --all`).

I assume this should work the same for the `init` task.

Comment: It also works for command line options of custom tasks: `withArguments("customTask", "--myArg", "myValue")` is the way to go (remove the call to `forTasks()` entirely).